# Energy necessary for brute-forcing or decryption

Tags: encryption

I am trying to understand how the physical limits of computation apply to crytography, and came up with the scenario below as a sort of *[gedanken](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thought_experiment)*. I would be grateful to see how others answer it.

Assume that Alice

1. used the default GnuPG (aka "GPG") settings, except for the following:

   - `--s2k-cipher-algo AES256`
   - `--s2k-digest-algo SHA512`
   - `--cert-digest-algo SHA512`
2. and then used GPG to create a 4096-bit RSA PGP encryption key pair whose private key is protected by a 10-word [Diceware](http://world.std.com/~reinhold/diceware.html) passphrase;
3. and then used the public key of that key pair to encrypt a plain text 1kB long;
4. and then stored the resulting ciphertext, along with the key pair, on a CD-ROM which she then gave to Bob, and nowhere else;
5. and then perished, vaporised by a meteorite along with the laptop she used to perform the above tasks, leaving Bob's CD the only record of her key pair and ciphertext.

Assume also the existence of a computer, bound by the physical limits of computation as presently understood (e.g. [these](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limits_to_computation)), but otherwise optimised to efficiently perform the tasks in question (e.g. a hypothetical quantum computer).

Finally, assume that this computer is adequately powered, and immune to catastrophes (such as the death of the Sun), during its tasks.

**What is the minimum energy, in [SI units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_System_of_Units) (i.e. J, or kJ, or MJ, etc), such a computer would require, in order to determine the plaintext, if the CD-ROM's data are available to it?**

Please explain your answer, thanks!

*P.S. Please migrate this question to security.stackexchange.com if you believe it would be more appropriate there.*

Comment: Don't you mean "...in order to determine the *plaintext*"?  The ciphertext is right on Bob's CD, and so it's no work at all to determine that.  Also, is Alice's public key available somewhere?

Comment: @poncho, thanks for catching that typo! And for your question. I've clarified my question accordingly :)

Comment: Is the private key really supposed to be on Bob's CD? $\;$

Comment: @RickyDemer, normally not: one would expect Alice to keep her private key private. But in this contrived scenario, yes, it really is supposed to be on Bob's CD. The point of the scenario is to create a situation in which Kerckhoffs's principle applies (or at least, something close to it): everything is known to the "attacker" except for the passphrase.

Comment: It seems like it would be far more relevant to consider what happens if the "attacker" has the public key and the password-encrypted private key, rather than the key pair. $\;$

Comment: @Ricky Demer: According to the [private key format](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4880#section-5.5.3), the public modulus is available in clear in the private key. A critical parameter is the value of the `s2kcount` parameter, which controls the [work factor used for  stretching of the passphrase](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4880#section-3.7.1.3). Depending on that, the point of least hardest attack is the passphrase, or the factorization of the public modulus. By default stretching used to hash about $2^{16}$ bytes, but I have read about plans to increase that.

Comment: The pass phrase in this case is about 129 bits of entropy. Together with stretching is is probably harder to attack than factoring the modulus. Symmetric algorithms may be harder to attack with a quantum computer than asymmetric algorithms for about the same amount of security. Or not?